# visual web part with Web services

Tags: web-services, visual-web-part

I have come accross a scenario wherein i have to debug an resolve a issue in a visual web part. I checked the code of web part and came to know that a  web service (asmx) has been used in it. I tried to run the visual web part project but i get error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Sample.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b831834871b59c1a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have been struggling to find a way to run this project.

Any help pointer is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't have the source code or DLL for Sample.WebService, you can always comment out the dependent parts.

Comment: Did you tried adding the `Service References` into your project?